# Button content disappears while using ControlTemplate in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wrote a style for my form and everything seems to work just fine, except I'm not getting a text on my button. The only thing I get is a grey button without content.

Here is what I tried:

```
<Style x:Key="CodeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Enter"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border 
                      Name="Border"
                      CornerRadius="4" 
                      Padding="10"
                      BorderBrush="#666666"
                      Background="#e5e5e5"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#90c74b"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BitmapEffect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="#90c74b" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="4" Opacity="0.7" Softness="0.8" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see at line 6, I want the content of the button to be "Enter".

Comment: use `ContentPresenter `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `ContentPresenter` inside your template for that text to be shown.

Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="CodeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Enter"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border 
                      Name="Border"
                      CornerRadius="4" 
                      Padding="10"
                      BorderBrush="#666666"
                      Background="#e5e5e5"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#90c74b"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BitmapEffect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="#90c74b" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="4" Opacity="0.7" Softness="0.8" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I figured I needed the ContentPresenter, but you showed me how to use it, so thanks!